# Simple C++ char array encryption function - Segment fault

Tags: c++, pointers, encryption, arrays

As always, problems with the pointers. I am trying to create a very simple "encryption/decryption" function for char arrays. Yes, I know I can use strings, but I want to improve my knowledge about pointers and make use of simple bytes to achieve a simple task.
So, I created a simple struct like this:

```
struct text {
    char* value;
    int size;
}
```

And I created this simple function:

```
text encrypt(text decrypted) {
    char key = 'X';
    for (int i=0; i<decrypted.size; i++) {
        decrypted.value[i] = decrypted.value[i] ^ (key + i) % 255);
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

At this point, an experienced C++ programmer should have spot the problem, I think. Anyway, I call this function like this:

```
...
text mytext;
mytext.value = new char[5];
mytext.value = "Hello";
mytext.size = 5;

mytext = encrypt(mytext);
...
```

I get, like always, a 'Segmentation fault(core dumped)' error. This is Linux, and, of course, g++. What have I done, again? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mytext.value = new char[5];
mytext.value = "Hello";
```

on the second line, you throw away the (handle to the) allocated memory, leaking it, and let `mytext.value` point to a string literal. Modifying a string literal is undefined behaviour, and usually crashes, since string literals are often stored in a read-only memory segment.

If you insist on using a `char*`, you should `strncpy` the string into the allocated memory (but be aware that it won't be 0-terminated then, you should better allocate a `new char[6]` and copy also the 0-terminator).

Or let `decrypt` create a new `text` that it returns:

```
text encrypt(text decrypted) {
    char key = 'X';
    text encrypted;
    encrypted.size = decrypted.size;
    encrypted.value = new char[encrypted.size];
    for (int i=0; i<decrypted.size; i++) {
        encrypted.value[i] = decrypted.value[i] ^ (key + i) % 255;
    }
    // What about 0-terminators?
    return encrypted;
}
```

But, as you're using C++, `std::string` would be a better choice here.

Comment: Doesn't the "throw away the (handle to the)" make that clear? Probably not clear enough.

Comment: Could I create a new char* inside the encrypt() function, fill it with the 'encrypted' characters, and return it?

Comment: @ali: Yes. It may not be the best idea around, but you certainly *could* do it.

Comment: @ali Yes, but you'd need to also create a new `text`, since you don't know whether the `value` field of the argument can be `delete`d or not. And you must know whether the `char*`s point to 0-terminated arrays or not.

Comment: Let see if I understand. I return the pointer of the new created text variable. Is this re-assigning the pointer to the variable being assigned the function? Don't I have to delete anything? What happens to the original content? Thanks! I learnt more about pointers today.

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying string literals:

```
mytext.value = "Hello";
```

after this, you can no longer legally mutate what `mytext.value` points to, you can only re-assign the pointer.

The fix: **use `std::string`**